# How can I free allocated memory when I use structs and pointers?

Tags: c, matrix, memory, memory-management

So I made a program that solves systems of equations or inverts matrices using Gaussian elimination but when I try to free the memory with free() it just doesn't work.
I tried it with free(mat.m), you'll see that in my code, it fails at 220th line, immediately after the free_matrix() function in the original code, with:

```
Thread 1 received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
free_matrix (mat=...) at main.c:220
220 }
#0  free_matrix (mat=...) at main.c:220
#1  0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

At this point, I have no idea how I could fix it and I'm really sad because writing the algorithm took about 13 hours from my life and it just doesn't work.

So any help is really appreciated!

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct matrix
{
    double *m;
    int N;
}   matrix_t;

void alloc_matrix(matrix_t* mat)
{
    mat->m = malloc(mat->N * mat->N * sizeof(double));
}


void read_matrix(FILE* f, matrix_t mat)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < mat.N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat.N; j++)
        {
            fscanf(f, "%lf", &mat.m[i * mat.N + j]);
        }
    }
}

void free_matrix(matrix_t mat)
{
        free(mat.m);
}



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* a_matrix = argv[1];
    int N = atoi(argv[2]);

    FILE* f1 = fopen(a_matrix, "r");

    matrix_t matrix;
    matrix.N = N;

    alloc_matrix(&matrix);
    read_matrix(f1, matrix);
    free_matrix(matrix);

    fclose(f1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).   If the problem reveals itself at line 220, it is unlikely you’ve got a minimal reproduction.

Comment: There's no `free_matrix()` function in the posted code.

Comment: You probably want `free(mat->m)`.

Comment: Oh I removed it but going to edit it!

Comment: Here we go! I updated it with that free_matrix() function!

Comment: @Barmar I tried that one and it didn't work too. ->main.c|219|error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'matrix_t {aka struct matrix}')|

Comment: You didn't have the `free_matrix()` function before, I assumed it was declared `matrix_t *mat`

Comment: So, in this way, I cannot use free() alone at all?

Comment: `free(mat.m)` should work.

Comment: Use `valgrind` to debug memory allocation problems.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that was an useful article, thank you! I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @Barmar The problem is that I don't use Linux. I just checked valgrind and it's a tool for Linux.

Comment: Are you still getting an error with this minimal version? it looks like it should work. The problem was probably due to undefined behavior in some other part of the program, which corrupted memory.

Comment: Thank you for reducing the code to an MCVE; there is a vast difference between 300 lines and 50 lines of code.  If no-one else answers, I may take another look at the reduced code later (18+ hours later, I mean).  One detail to check: does the problem reproduce for you with the code now shown?  I tried it on a Mac under Valgrind and didn't get any problems specific to your code.  I used a 4x4 random matrix of integers between 10 and 99.  What data causes a crash for you?  That is part of an MCVE too.

Comment: [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) complains about all sorts of things when your original 300-line program is run.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Nothing special data, I used, for the original, a 3X3 matrix of integers.  In the original code there is another Nx1 matrix (vector), Ax=b, The b but that has the same functions as this one, only with smaller size. The same goes for the NxN identity matrix that the program creates, so as it seems it isnt exactly the problem, shall I make another question with a reduced code specifically for gaussian elimination? where I got problem.